# Change default font in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

Is it possible to change the default font in netbeans? The documentation says:

> The font Monospaced is maped to different fonts on different systems.
>   On Windows it is mapped to "Courier ", on Linux it is mapped to
>   "Lucida Typewriter".

http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/editor_fonts_colors/Editor_fonts_and_colors.htm

I'm on windows and want to map Monospaced font to 'Consolas' instead of 'Courier'.

P.S. I know that fonts can easily be changed from options, but when I change it in this way, I can no longer use unicode characters. Guess I need to do what they call 'mapping' the monospaced font to other font.

Comment: Are you sure Consolas supports the characters you need?

Comment: Wikipedia says Consolas only has about half as many as Courier New, so that could be why.

Comment: Neither Courier supports these characters. The documentation also says: _Monospaced also covers other characters from Unicode subset which are not included in Courier or Lucida_

Comment: So as far as I can figure out they use courier for standard english alphabet and they also include other unicode characters from another source.

Comment: Sounds like font fallback only works with standard font aliases? Strange.

Comment: On Linux you can change these font aliases by fiddling with fontconfig (add your alias to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` with a high priority). I don't know how on Windows.

Comment: I think this link can help you:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/32624/ugly-fonts-in-netbeans-how-can-i-make-it-use-the-system-font

Comment: Funny almost 8 years later people are still trying to change the default font in netbeans :D

Answer (score 12):

Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors

Set the category "Default", and to the right of that, the font you want to use.

If this does not fix it, try adding:

```
--laf Nimbus -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

or

```
-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd --laf Metal
```

to the file : `netbeans.conf`. You can find it in `$NETBEANS_HOME/etc/` folder. Make your application font smaller from system preferences.

Comment: Set my default font to consolas, tried to add both of the configuration lines but still when I try to type using unicode characters I get some unknown symbols instead...

Answer (score 7):

To change the font size outside of the editor you can configure by editing the Net Beans conf file, you can find it here:
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc\netbeans.conf

Then edit this line:
netbeans_default_options="..."

by adding this at the end:

--fontsize 18

I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

Life becomes more easier now. Just from **Tools** menu choose **Options** and then follow steps on the following screen shot and take care with step 3 and 4 which they are making the default font for all languages:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a NetBeans plugin called 'UI-Editor' which allows you to customize virtually any Swing property, including font sizes, colors, and types. Go to Tools->Plugins and search for 'UI-Editor' or go here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55618/?show=true

Answer (score 0):

also don't not forget to change the font to the one that support Arabic like Arial for example i am not sure of some one mention that i just tried it

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell there's no way to do this. jEdit (http://jedit.org) also uses Swing and DOES do font substitution for all fonts - there's a "automatic font substitution" checkbox in Global Options > Text Area, along with a list of preferred fonts. But jEdit is otherwise not as capable as Netbeans.